# DBD::SQLite::db commit failed: disk I/O error

Tags: sqlite

I have a system writing data to an sqlite file. I had everything operational under CentOS 8. After upgrading the system to Rocky Linux 9 I see this error when running a commit command: `DBD::SQLite::db commit failed: disk I/O error`

I have checked file permissions, disk space, SMART readings, everything disk related that I can think of but without success.

Has anyone encountered this error before? What could I try to fix it?

Comment: Have you updated your Perl libraries, too?

Comment: Can you write to the sqlite file directly?

Comment: I have updated Perl with the system updated and I installed all the modules I am using. I can write to the sqlite file directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a missing Perl module (LWP::https) that was causing DBD::SQLite not to get the data it wanted. Apparently, DBD::SQLite says Disk I/O error for that case.